# Simple question about $.post and a PHP sum

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

I have a jQuery $.post function sending data to a PHP file which updates a DB field, grabs 1 of the values being sent to the file, adds '1' and returns the new value.

My PHP file looks as follows:

```
$varID = $_GET['varID'];
$varKey = $_GET['varKey'];
$varCurrentValue = ($_GET['varCurrentValue'] + 1);

update_comment_meta($varID, $varKey, $varCurrentValue);

echo $varCurrentValue;
```

My firebug response, if I'm understanding it correctly, confirms that the value's are being sent correctly to the PHP file: http://cl.ly/2P1Y0E3710442V3I143K [img]

However the only response that I'm getting is the "1" that I'm adding in the 3rd line of code, not the value of the sum that I should be getting.

I'm sure it's something really simple, but I'm just not seeing it...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the `$.post` call look like?

Comment: `$('.ilikethis').click(function() { 
  var varID = $(this).attr('varID');
  var varKey = $(this).attr('varKey');
  var varCurrentValue = $(this).attr('varCurrentValue');
 
  $.post("http://localhost/site/wp-content/themes/site/includes/postlike.php",
  { varID : varID , varKey : varKey, varCurrentValue : varCurrentValue },
 function(data){
  $(this).html(data);
 }
  );
return false;
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you are reading GET from php and sending POST.

Change to

```
$varID = $_POST['varID'];
$varKey = $_POST['varKey'];
$varCurrentValue = ($_POST['varCurrentValue'] + 1);

update_comment_meta($varID, $varKey, $varCurrentValue);

echo $varCurrentValue;
```

You can always just use $_REQUEST[] which will give you both GET and POST as well.

Comment: the response etc is correct and the DB is being updated, but the link value isn't being updated as expected.

Surely `$(this).text(data);` should do it?

Comment: hmmm... typically you wouldn't be passing the data to $(this). Although I'm not sure how your $.post is written. Often you have an anonymous function that passes in 'data' and then apply that data with a jquery selector. `$.post('myrequest.php', function(data) { $('#somediv').text(data); });`

Comment: I think that's what I've done already:


$.post("http://localhost/site/wp-content/themes/site/includes/postlike.php",
{ varID : varID , varKey : varKey, varCurrentValue : varCurrentValue },
function(data){
$(this).html(data);
}
);

Comment: Sorry, I meant the context of $(this). It is likely that you should swap out $(this) with the jquery selector for the actual element you are trying to insert the text into. For example if the text was in `<p id="show_value">2</p>` you could use `$('#show_value').text(data)` as opposed to `$(this).text(data)`

Comment: ah ok.. the only problem with that, is there's a bunch of these items (its a voting type system for posts on a page), so if I use the selector, then all of them will change, when I only want the clicked one to change

Comment: Sorted... Added a unique ID to each of the voting elements and use that ID to set the text without using $(this).

Thanks for the help @Mike

Comment: That's why I was curious about the context of the $(this). You will have to grab the $(this) before the $.post() like `var $myObj = $(this)` and then use that inside the $.post() like `$.post('myrequest.php', function(data) { $myObj.text(data); });` If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're posting data, use the `$_POST[]` php variable to retrieve the values. `$_GET[]` is only for the parameters passed via the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the other answers about using `$_GET` when you should have been using `$_POST` -

If you use the `$_REQUEST` superglobal it merges `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` so you can switch which method you use in JavaScript without having to change the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you are sending data using `HTTP POST` and getting them in PHP using `$_GET` which refers to `HTTP GET`, you should get data using `$_POST` in PHP or send data using `HTTP GET` in jQuery.

Hope it helps.